# Error when use custom DQL function with Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Symfony 2 and the ORM Doctrine. I want to create and register a custom DQL function. In fact, I want to use the SQL function "[CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)" in my request, like this :

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('d')
       ->from('\Test\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'd')
       ->orderBy('CAST(d.myField AS UNSIGNED)', 'ASC')

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

For this, I have created a "CastFunction" who extend "FunctionNode" :

```
namespace Test\MyBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

class CastFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $firstDateExpression = null;
    public $secondDateExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->firstDateExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $this->secondDateExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf('CAST(%s AS %s)', $this->firstDateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker), $this->secondDateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker));
    }
}
```

Of course, I have registered this class in my config.yml :

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                CAST: Test\MyBundle\DQL\CastFunction
```

Now, when I try my request, I obtain the following error:

"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'UNSIGNED)': Error: 'UNSIGNED' is not defined."

I search but I don't where is the problem!

Have you got a idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After several search, I have finally found the solution. I had two problems: first my parse function was wrong, second, I called a SQL function in my orderBy (thank you [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad)).

So, here is my correct class:

```
namespace Ypok\YPoliceBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

class CastFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $firstDateExpression = null;
    public $unit = null;    

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->firstDateExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_AS);

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
        $this->unit = $lexer->token['value'];

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf('CAST(%s AS %s)',  $this->firstDateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker), $this->unit);
    }
}
```

And now, I can use perfectly the SQL function 'CAST' in my repository:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('d, CAST(d.myField AS UNSIGNED) AS sortx')
   ->from('\Test\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'd')
   ->orderBy('sortx', 'ASC')

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Best regards

Comment: How have you accessed "sortx" property through object ?

Answer (score 2):

Can't find the reference but functions are not allowed in the order by clause.  You need to cast your value in the select statement then sort by it.

Something like:

```
$qb->select('d, CAST(d.myField AS UNSIGNED) AS sortx)
   ->from('\Test\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'd')
   ->orderBy('sortx, 'ASC')
```

That is assuming your CAST function is written correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have already tried this code and issue persists. I think that the problem come from "parse" function of "CastFunction" class. But I don't understand where.