# How To Group By The Date Part Only In Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to group my results by the date not the date time in doctrine.

Here is my group by statement of my query:

```
 GROUP BY CAST(fbaoh.datetimePlaced AS DATE) HAVING sqty > 1 ORDER BY fbaoh.datetimePlaced DESC
```

This works in MySQL but not in Doctrine, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the error I get:

```
 Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Thanks!

Here is my entire query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("
SELECT fbaoh, fbaoh.id as fbaohid, sum(fbaoh.qty) as sqty, p.id, p.name
FROM WIC\APIBundle\Entity\FBAOrderHistory fbaoh
LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingAmazon la
WITH fbaoh.asin = la.standardProductIdValue
LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing l
WITH fbaoh.sku = l.product_identifier
LEFT JOIN WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product p
WITH l.product = p.id
LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingChannel lc
WITH l.listingChannel = lc.id
WHERE fbaoh.webServiceAccountAmazon = lc.webServiceAccount
AND fbaoh.sku = :sku
AND l.id = la.id
AND p.id != ''
GROUP BY CAST(fbaoh.datetimePlaced AS DATE) HAVING sqty > 1 ORDER BY fbaoh.datetimePlaced DESC
");
```

Comment: have you tried using `DATE()` instead of `CAST`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Either way I get this error: Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable. (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do: [Big props to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096429/error-when-use-custom-dql-function-with-doctrine-and-symfony2).

I had to create an extended class so that I could use the CAST function.

```
namespace YOUR\NAME\SPACE;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class CastFunction extends FunctionNode
{
public $firstDateExpression = null;
public $unit = null;    

public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
{
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
    $this->firstDateExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_AS);

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
    $this->unit = $lexer->token['value'];

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
}

public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return sprintf('CAST(%s AS %s)',  $this->firstDateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),    
$this->unit);
    }
}
```

Register it in the config.yml

```
 doctrine:
      orm:
           dql:
                string_functions:
                     CAST: Test\MyBundle\DQL\CastFunction
```

Then use it in my query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("
SELECT fbaoh, CAST(fbaoh.datetimePlaced AS DATE) AS groupDateGrp, fbaoh.id as fbaohid, sum(fbaoh.qty) as sqty, p.id, p.name
FROM WIC\APIBundle\Entity\FBAOrderHistory fbaoh
LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingAmazon la
WITH fbaoh.asin = la.standardProductIdValue
LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\Listing l
WITH fbaoh.sku = l.product_identifier
LEFT JOIN WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product p
WITH l.product = p.id
LEFT JOIN WIC\ListingBundle\Entity\ListingChannel lc
WITH l.listingChannel = lc.id
WHERE fbaoh.webServiceAccountAmazon = lc.webServiceAccount
AND fbaoh.sku = :sku
AND l.id = la.id
AND p.id != ''
GROUP BY groupDateGrp HAVING sqty > 1 ORDER BY fbaoh.datetimePlaced DESC
");
```